# Парсер ссылок в выдаче google

Tags: delphi, google-search

Всем привет. Пишу парсер выдачи Гоши и столкнулся с некой проблемой. Мне нужно получить ссылки на сайт с найденной странице, т.е. отправляю запрос:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=+edit1.text
```

И получаю html код страницыкод 
Код:

```
Source:= IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.google.com/search?q='+edit1.text);
```

Затем нахожу все ссылки со страницы следующим кодом
Код:

```
while Pos('href="', Source) <> 0 do begin
Delete(Source, 1, Pos('href="', Source) + Length('href="') - 1);
ListBox1.Items.Add(Copy(Source, 1, Pos('"', Source) - 1));
Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Вся эта шайтан-машина работает, но ссылки получаю в виде редиректа, а хотелось бы, чтобы были именно прямые ссылки. Видел в некоторых прогах такое исполнение, но исходников не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Вот заметил в твоем коде одну не то, чтобы ошибку, но скорее уязвимость в строчке:

```
while Pos('href="', Source) <> 0 do
```

Конкретнее,

```
Pos('href="', Source)
```

А еще точнее в этой искомой подстроке:

```
'href="'
```

Могу тебе точно сказать, что далеко не все веб-разработчики используют двойные кавычки
при заключении адреса сайта в параметре "href". Кто-то заключает адрес сайта в одинарные, кто-то в двойные, так, что лучше ищи в полученном HTML-коде не `'href="'`, а `'href='`.
Это снизит твою уязвимость. Ну, а чтобы устранить эту уязвимость полностью, тебе надо полученный в результате GET-запроса HTML-код преобразовывать в нижний регистр, используя функцию `lowercase`. Сам понимаешь, кто-то напишет "`HrEf`", кто-то "`href`"...

Ну, и далее искать в полученном с сайта коде слова "`href=`"

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы чтобы не парится с поиском `href`, не загрузить результат в `TWebBrowser` и там уже пройтись по ссылкам в DOM-модели?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, эта задача не так легко решается, гугл меняет разметку очень часто, поэтому обычный парс не всегда будет работать.

Во вторых, если сильно нужно - есть платное апи, удобное для разработчика, для поиска.

рекомендую таки с ним ознакомится.